# "Eu amo ela" está incorreto por quê?

Tags: pronomes, caso-gramatical, pronomes-oblíquos

Sempre aprendi que *eu amo ela* é errado (o correto é *eu a amo*).

É apenas por causa do [cacófato](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacofonia) *amo ela* (que soa como *a moela*) ou há alguma outra explicação?

Comment: Na versão europeia o correto é "eu amo-a".

Comment: @AméricoTavares "eu a amo" também não seria incorreto, embora incomum.

Comment: @E_net4 tem razão: altera a posição normal do pronome, mas pode de facto acontecer, sem ser necessariamente errado.

Comment: Já pensou por que motivo, mesmo no "liberal" Inglês, ninguém diz "I love she", mas "I love her"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Além do *cacófato* (que também aconteceria em outros casos como: "**eu vi ela**" [viéla] em vez de "**eu a vi**"), o pronome está sendo mal empregado: *ele(s)* e *ela(s)* são pronomes pessoais do caso reto e só podem ser usados na função de sujeito. Para complementos verbais, devemos usar os pronomes oblíquos (*o, a, os, as, lhe, lhes*).

Para mais referências dê uma olhada nesse [artigo](http://www2.tvcultura.com.br/aloescola/linguaportuguesa/morfologia/pronomes-usocultoepopular2.htm).

Comment: Na variante europeia da língua, eu *amo-a*, eu *via-a*.

Comment: ".....só podem ser usados na função de sujeito"  O que dizer então de "eu trouxe isto para ele" ou "eu comprei isto para ela"?

Answer (score 2):

Nunca devemos dizer "eu amo ela", "eu vi ela", e sim "eu a amo", "eu a vi". Isto vale para o verbo no infinitivo acompanhado de pronome pessoal. Exemplo: ao invés de dizer "conhecer ela", prefira dizer "conhecê-la".

Comment: em pt-PT diríamos `eu amo-a` e `eu vi-a`

Answer (score -1):

NARISS-D man , se liga. 
Existem certas classes de palavras que se atraem. 
A matéria é colocação de pronomes onde os mesmos são classificados como: Ênclise, mesóclise e próclise. 
Ênclise (Pronome no final do verbo): Chamei-a para casa.
Mesóclise (Pronome no meio do verbo) : Chamá-la-ei para casa.
Próclise (Pronome antes do verbo) : Eu a chamei para casa.

A maioria dos casos é feito por ênclise, entretanto deve-se ficar alerta com o uso dos demais , pois nem sempre conseguimos encaixar uma ênclise de modo que esteja correta. Como você deve saber toda regra tem sua exceção , portanto quando não se dá pra usa-la optamos por próclise ou mesóclise.
Mesóclise só ocorrerá com o verbo no futuro do presente, enquanto próclise ocorrerá de modo que tais classes gramaticais iram atrair o pronome para perto do verbo. 
Como dito acima NARISS-D foi algo que eu vi em algum lugar , um tempo atrás e veio a calhar no momento.

Negativos
Advérbios
Relativos
Indefinidos
Sujeito
Subordinadas (conjunções)
Demostrativos