# Why "te amo" is considered grammatically incorrect? (Por que "te amo" é considerado gramaticalmente incorreto?)

Tags: gramática, português-brasileiro

Brazilians have the habit of saying "te amo", however it is said that it's grammatically incorrect.

Why?

---

Os brasileiros têm o costume de falar "te amo", porém é dito que é gramaticalmente incorreto dizer assim.

Por quê?

Comment: Relacionada: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/346/eu-amo-ela-est%C3%A1-incorreto-por-qu%C3%AA

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Não é exatamente incorreto.

"Te" é pronome pessoal do caso oblíquo, no caso, na segunda pessoa do singular. No Brasil, por exemplo, é mais comum usar a terceira pessoa do singular. Portanto, não é totalmente incorreto dizer:

> Eu te amo.

É apenas incomum (exceto para alguns estados, como Santa Catarina e Rio Grande do Sul, onde a segunda pessoa do singular é usada com frequência). Agora, é incorreto dizer apenas:

> Te amo.

Isto porque não se inicia frase com pronome pessoal. Analogamente, é incorreto dizer:

> Lhe digo uma coisa.

O correto é:

> Digo-lhe uma coisa.

Portanto, se o autor da frase quer omitir o pronome pessoal do caso reto ("eu"), isto é possível, a frase fica correta sendo dita da seguinte forma:

> Amo-te.

[Aqui tem uma explicação mais aprofundada](http://www.professorsabbag.com.br/arquivos/artigos_do_prof/fla/1251993382eu_te_amo.pdf).

Comment: Em Portugal usa-se mais dizer amo-te, desejo-te, quero-te.

Comment: É incorreto pois a gramática diz que não se inicia frase com pronome oblíquo, mesmo porque este pronome não conjuga verbos. Algum gramático decidiu que o  'Te' de "te amo" torna-se sujeito da frase, acredito.